# Break After doesn't have visual effect

Tags: html, css

```css
h1 {
  display: inline;
  break-after: page;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

```html
        <h1>This is Page 1</h1>
<h1>This is Page 2</h1>
<h1>This is Page 3</h1>
```

I make h1 display inline-block because h1 block element by default
to test break-after.....

My Problem is break-after doesn't make any visual effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
h1 {
  break-after: page;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is Page 1</h1>
<h1>This is Page 2</h1>
<h1>This is Page 3</h1>
```

You are using `display: inline` . So CSS is doing it first which restricts the page break. You can not apply two contradictory designs in one tag. Use class instead.

If you want page break, remove `display: inline`

Comment: ok can you tell me what is break-inside and thanks very mush

Comment: The```break-inside``` sets how page, column, or region breaks should behave inside a generated box. If there is no generated box, the property is ignored.

As, comment section is a small space I couldn't show you the example. For example please [visit here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_break-inside.asp)